# Fetch POST headers - iOS Safari issues

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, post, fetch

I'm sending data w/ headers to my server from the client (https client on my heroku domain) without any issue on Chrome mobile but iOS safari won't POST the data.

Below javascript sits on the client side and pulls data from the geolocation API in the users mobile browser (after asking for permission). Both Chrome mobile and iOS Safari get to the step of asking the user for geolocation approval, but then iOS safari sends another 'GET' to the endpoint instead of a 'POST' like Chrome mobile.

```
const status = "Y";
const guest = cookies.guest_id;
const data = { status, guest };

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
};
fetch(`/events/${eventID}/prompt`, options) // my endpoint
```

My understanding is fetch() is [fully supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) by iOS mobile, so why isn't it executing as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here in Safari on iOS 15.5. Simple request

```
fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'POST'
});
```

is done as `GET` with a 405 as resulting answer.

As stated in the discussion of https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/447, added the `mode: 'cors` option and it works also in Safari on iOS 15.5.

```
fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors'
});
```

I hope this helps others. Unfortunately, I was not able to identify the reason for this behavior.